# Expected value of doubling or halving a number with equal probability

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have this question that you start with a value say c. At each step, you either double or half the value with equal probability. Let $X_i$ be the value of c at ith-step, I need to find the expected value of $X_n$.

Here is my approach. Somehow when I run a simulation against this result. It doesn't look correct.

Let $I_i \in \{2, \frac{1}{2} \}$ be the random variable for multiplication factor at $i$th step and $c$ be starting value. Since $I_i$ are i.i.d, $X_n \sim B(n, \frac{1}{2}) $
$$ P(X_n = c\frac{2^i}{2^{n-i}}) = \binom{n}{i} \frac{1}{2^n} $$ 
$$ E(X_n) = c \sum^n_{i=0} \frac{2^i}{2^{n-i}} \binom{n}{i} \frac{1}{2^n} = c \sum^n_{i=0} \binom{n}{i} \frac{1}{4^{n-i}} = c (\frac{5}{4})^n $$

I want to know what went wrong in my approach.

Update: 
Here is my code to simulate it:

```
totalSteps= 1000;
emeans = zeros(1, totalSteps);
tmeans = zeros(1, totalSteps);
for step=1:totalSteps
    samples = 100;
    x = ones(samples, step);
    s = zeros(samples, 1);
    for j=1:samples  
        for i = 2: step;
          if rand() > 0.5
            x(j,i) = x(j,i-1)*0.5;
          else
            x(j, i) = x(j,i-1) * 2;
          end
        end
        s(j) = mean(x(j,:));
    end
    emean = mean(s);
    emeans(step) = mean(s);
    tmeans(step) = (5/4)^step;
end
plot(log(emeans));
plot(log(tmeans));
```

[image: Green is the theoretical expected value along with increasing steps. blue is the simulated expected value]

Comment: What is your question? How to solve the problem or what is wrong with your approach?

Comment: I want to know if my approach is correct or not. I wrote a program to do this and the output is way off.

Comment: A simpler way is to write $X_n = cI_1I_2\cdots I_n$ and take expectations of both sides.  But your way is correct also, so the simulation must be off.

Comment: your calculation looks correct

Comment: Or write a recurrence.

Comment: The way I simulate it is to generate a random number and see if it is > 0.5 , if so times 2, else divide by 2.  But I am getting results that is a lot smaller than what is predicted above consistently.

Comment: Are you generating uniform [0,1]?  And are you fixing a particular n, say, n=4? Then run a million times generating indepnedent versions of X_4.  Should converge to (5/4)^4. In C I think the command is X= rand()*1.0/RAND_MAX to generate a uniform.

Comment: I am using  Matlab. I think rand() is between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know MatLab, but looking at your code, it looks like you are making a list of values $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ and taking the mean of that list.  However, what you want is to take the mean of many $X_n$s for one fixed $n$ (the number of iterations).

Comment: What I did was for each $n$ in $X_n$, I run the simulation 100 times and average to find the simulated $E_sX_n$.  Then I compare it with the theoretical $EX_n$.  I was curious about how far off my result was, so I do that for each n and plot to see how my simulated result for $E_sX_n$ diverges from the theoretical $EX_n$

Comment: Is $j$ the run number, because if so, it looks like you're finding, for each run, $s(j)=$ (mean of $X_1,..., X_n$) for each given run.  But you should be averaging all the $X_1$s to (hopefully) get a result of approximately $1.25c$, and then average all the $X_2$s to get a result of approximately $1.25^2 c$; and so on.

Comment: Oh wow. Nice catch. As you said, I was taking the mean wrong. Thank you for saving me hours of headaches : )

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help.  Interesting puzzle!